# ckeditor dataDowncast - I can not use both markerToData and markerToHighlight at the same time

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor5-plugin

I have a ckeditor5 custom plugin and I have to convert markers to data for saving into the database.

This is the model: X[Y]Z

The marker name is "my-highlight:1"

This is what I would like to have:

`X<my-highlight-start name="1"></my-highlight-start><span class="my-highlight">Y</span><my-highlight-end name="1"></mű-highlight-end>Z`

So I need both start/end tags at the beginning and at the end of the marker range and also spans around the text nodes.

What I can do:

`X<my-highlight-start name="1"></my-highlight-start>Y<my-highlight-end name="1"></my-highlight-end>Z`

or

`X<span class="my-highlight">Y</span><Z`

But not both at the same time.

I need spans because I have to highlight the text in browsers and I need start/end tags because highlights can be overlapped and user can add remarks for the highlights.

So my output after processing will be like this:

X<sup>(1)</sup>Y<sup>(1)</sup>Z

1. User remark for Y

For overlapping cases:

X<sup>(1)</sup><sup>(2)</sup>AB<sup>(2)</sup>C<sup>(3)</sup>D<sup>(1)</sup>Z<sup>(3)</sup>

1. User remark for ABCD
2. User remark for AB
3. User remark for DZ

Here is a part of my plugin configuration:

```
editor.conversion.for('dataDowncast')
    .markerToHighlight(data_markerToHighlightConfig)
    .markerToData(data_markerToDataConfig);
```

Seems to me that both can not work like this. Here only markerToData works. If I add only one of them that works, so my configuration for markerToHighlight and markerToData can be OK.
I debugged, and when I add both, only markerToData called.

Here are the configs:

```
const data_markerToDataConfig = {
    model: "my-highlight"
};

const data_markerToHighlightConfig = {
    model: "my-highlight",
    view: { classes: "my-highlight" }
};
```

In action on-line:
https://peterborkuti.github.io/ckeditor-bphighlight/

**In action, see the console for the getData():**

When both converters are enabled, only star/end markers are there (BAD)
[image]

When only markerToHighlight is enabled, only spans are there (OK)
[image]

When only markerToData is enabled, only start/end markers are there (OK)
[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from ckeditor support. I am not sure, if I can share the original answer publicly, but the cause is:

markerToData and markerToHighlight can not be used together by design. This information is missing from the documentation. To deal with the situation, a custom converter should be written.

When I am done with the custom converter, I will share it here.